# Screen Manager in kivy doesn't work

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

i'm a beginner and i'm trying to do this program with a Menu screen, where the play button run the 2048 game code. The problem is that it doesn't bind with the class for playing the game. It only appears the kivy file part. Obviously here the menu must be implemented, it's just a test with two buttons.

## main.py

```
from __future__ import division
import random
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, WipeTransition
from kivy.core.window import Window, Keyboard
from kivy.graphics import Color, BorderImage
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label

spacing = 15

colors = (
    'eee4da', 'ede0c8', 'f2b179', 'f59563',
    'f67c5f', 'f65e3b', 'edcf72', 'edcc61',
    'edc850', 'edc53f', 'edc22e')

tile_colors = {2 ** i: color for i, color in
               enumerate(colors, start=1)}

key_vectors = {
    Keyboard.keycodes['up']: (0, 1),
    Keyboard.keycodes['right']: (1, 0),
    Keyboard.keycodes['down']: (0, -1),
    Keyboard.keycodes['left']: (-1, 0),
}


class Tile(Widget):
    font_size = NumericProperty(24)
    number = NumericProperty(2)
    color = ListProperty(get_color_from_hex(tile_colors[2]))
    number_color = ListProperty(get_color_from_hex('776e65'))

    def __init__(self, number=2, **kwargs):
        super(Tile, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_size = 0.5 * self.width
        self.number = number
        self.update_colors()

    def update_colors(self):
        self.color = get_color_from_hex(tile_colors[self.number])
        if self.number > 4:
            self.number_color = get_color_from_hex('f9f6f2')

    def resize(self, pos, size):
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size
        self.font_size = 0.5 * self.width


def all_cells(flip_x=False, flip_y=False):
    for x in (reversed(range(4)) if flip_x else range(4)):
        for y in (reversed(range(4)) if flip_y else range(4)):
            yield (x, y)


class Board(Widget):
    b = None
    moving = False


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Board, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.resize()

    def reset(self):
        self.b = [[None for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
        self.new_tile()
        self.new_tile()

    def new_tile(self, *args):
        empty_cells = [(x, y) for x, y in all_cells()
                       if self.b[x][y] is None]
        if not empty_cells:
            print('Game over (tentative: no cells)')
            return

        x, y = random.choice(empty_cells)
        tile = Tile(pos=self.cell_pos(x, y),
                    size=self.cell_size)
        self.b[x][y] = tile
        self.add_widget(tile)

        if len(empty_cells) == 1 and self.is_deadlocked():
            print('Game over (board is deadlocked)')

        self.moving = False

    def is_deadlocked(self):
        for x, y in all_cells():
            if self.b[x][y] is None:
                return False

            number = self.b[x][y].number
            if self.can_combine(x + 1, y, number) or \
                    self.can_combine(x, y + 1, number):
                return False
        return True

    def move(self, dir_x, dir_y):
        if self.moving:
            return

        dir_x = int(dir_x)
        dir_y = int(dir_y)

        for board_x, board_y in all_cells(dir_x > 0, dir_y > 0):
            tile = self.b[board_x][board_y]
            if not tile:
                continue

            x, y = board_x, board_y
            while self.can_move(x + dir_x, y + dir_y):
                self.b[x][y] = None
                x += dir_x
                y += dir_y
                self.b[x][y] = tile

            if self.can_combine(x + dir_x, y + dir_y, tile.number):
                self.b[x][y] = None
                x += dir_x
                y += dir_y
                self.remove_widget(self.b[x][y])
                self.b[x][y] = tile
                tile.number *= 2
                if (tile.number == 2048):
                    print('You win the game')

                tile.update_colors()

            if x == board_x and y == board_y:
                continue  # nothing has happened

            anim = Animation(pos=self.cell_pos(x, y),
                             duration=0.25, transition='linear')
            if not self.moving:
                anim.on_complete = self.new_tile
                self.moving = True

            anim.start(tile)

    def valid_cell(self, board_x, board_y):
        return (board_x >= 0 and board_y >= 0 and
                board_x <= 3 and board_y <= 3)

    def can_move(self, board_x, board_y):
        return (self.valid_cell(board_x, board_y) and
                self.b[board_x][board_y] is None)

    def can_combine(self, board_x, board_y, number):
        return (self.valid_cell(board_x, board_y) and
                self.b[board_x][board_y] is not None and
                self.b[board_x][board_y].number == number)

    def cell_pos(self, board_x, board_y):
        return (self.x + board_x * (self.cell_size[0] + spacing) + spacing,
                self.y + board_y * (self.cell_size[1] + spacing) + spacing)

    def resize(self, *args):
        self.cell_size = (0.25 * (self.width - 5 * spacing), ) * 2

        # redraw background
        self.canvas.before.clear()
        with self.canvas.before:
            BorderImage(pos=self.pos, size=self.size, source='board.png')
            Color(*get_color_from_hex('ccc0b4'))
            for board_x, board_y in all_cells():
                BorderImage(pos=self.cell_pos(board_x, board_y),
                            size=self.cell_size, source='cell.png')

        # resize tiles
        if not self.b:
            return
        for board_x, board_y in all_cells():
            tile = self.b[board_x][board_y]
            if tile:
                tile.resize(pos=self.cell_pos(board_x, board_y),
                            size=self.cell_size)

    on_pos = resize
    on_size = resize

    def on_key_down(self, window, key, *args):
        if key in key_vectors:
            self.move(*key_vectors[key])

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        v = Vector(touch.pos) - Vector(touch.opos)
        if v.length() < 20:
            return

        if abs(v.x) > abs(v.y):
            v.y = 0
        else:
            v.x = 0

        self.move(*v.normalize())


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        board = self.root.ids.board
        board.reset()
        Window.bind(on_key_down=board.on_key_down)
        return Manager(transition=WipeTransition())




if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('faf8ef')
    GameApp().run()
```

## game.kv

```
#:set padding 20

FloatLayout:
    Board:
        id: board
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: (None, None)
        center: root.center
        size: [min(root.width, root.height) - 2 * padding] * 2

<Tile>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: self.color

        BorderImage:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'cell.png'

    Label:
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size
        bold: True
        color: root.number_color
        font_size: root.font_size
        text: str(root.number)

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager


    Screen:
        name: 'home'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Play'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: 100
                text_size: self.size
                on_press: root.current = 'game'
            Button:
                text: 'Options'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: 100
                text_size: self.size



    Screen:
        name: 'game'
        Board:
            id: game
```

Comment: What is the meaning of *The problem is that it does not bind with the class for playing the game*?

Comment: I see that you have created 2 Board, one under a FloatLayout and another under Screen, why have you created 2 Board?

Comment: @eyllanesc i made two board because i found online that the screen manager was made that way, so i called the the class board like in the py file. The meaning of that sentence is that when i run the code it appears the menu, when i click on play i see just the layout but it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have created 2 Boards, and the one you see is the board that is under Screen and that has never been reset or linked with the keyboard, the solution is to create only one, reset and link with the keys in the constructor.

***.kv**

```
#:set padding 20

<Tile>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: self.color

        BorderImage:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'cell.png'

    Label:
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size
        bold: True
        color: root.number_color
        font_size: root.font_size
        text: str(root.number)

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    Screen:
        name: 'home'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Play'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: 100
                text_size: self.size
                on_press: root.current = 'game'
            Button:
                text: 'Options'
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size: 100
                text_size: self.size

    Screen:
        name: 'game'
        Board:
            id: garme
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            size_hint: (None, None)
            center: root.center
            size: [min(root.width, root.height) - 2 * padding] * 2
```

***.py**

```
[...]

class Board(Widget):
    b = None
    moving = False
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Board, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.resize()
        self.reset()
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)

    [...]

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager(transition=WipeTransition())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('faf8ef')
    GameApp().run()
```